# Why do i get this error with NaitiveUI when i have done everything right?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my Gta v mod menu, i keep getting this error, the game runs fine but my mod menu doesn't work:

```
 at line 11: The type or namespace name 'NativeUI' was not found (missing a 'using' directive or assembly reference?)
   at line 17: The type or namespace name 'MenuPool' was not found (missing a 'using' directive or assembly reference?)
   at line 18: The type or namespace name 'UIMenu' was not found (missing a 'using' directive or assembly reference?)
   at line 20: The type or namespace name 'UIMenuItem' was not found (missing a 'using' directive or assembly reference?)
   at line 37: The type or namespace name 'UIMenu' was not found (missing a 'using' directive or assembly reference?)
   at line 37: The type or namespace name 'UIMenuItem' was not found (missing a 'using' directive or assembly reference?)
```

I dont know what to do here is the code, as you can see i have referenced all GTA libaries and also the NaitiveUI libary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using GTA;
using GTA.Math;
using GTA.Native;
using NativeUI;

namespace GtaMod
{
    public class GalaxyMenu : Script
    {
        MenuPool modMenuPool;
        UIMenu mainMenu;

        UIMenuItem SuperSwim;

        public GalaxyMenu()
        {
            Tick += onTick;
            KeyDown += onKeyDown;

            modMenuPool = new MenuPool();
            mainMenu = new UIMenu("Galaxy Menu", "SELECT AN OPTION");
            modMenuPool.Add(mainMenu);

            SuperSwim = new UIMenuItem("Super Swim");
            mainMenu.AddItem(SuperSwim);
            mainMenu.OnItemSelect += onMainMenuSelectItem;

        }

        void onMainMenuSelectItem(UIMenu sender, UIMenuItem item, int index)
        {
            if (item == SuperSwim)
            {
                Game.Player.SetSwimSpeedMultThisFrame(10000);
            }
        }



        void onTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (modMenuPool != null)
            {
                modMenuPool.ProcessMenus();
            }

        }

        void onKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F9 && !modMenuPool.IsAnyMenuOpen())
            {
                mainMenu.Visible = !mainMenu.Visible;   

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Fill text because stackoverflow is fricked, i cant write anymore to my description

Comment: I assume this is related to https://github.com/crosire/scripthookvdotnet ?

Comment: Where do you get those errors listed? In-game? In an IDE?

Comment: No, we can see that you have `using` directives. We cannot see if you have the right references. The error message is referring to *two different things*, and you need to make sure of both.

Comment: I get the error in a console ingame but also in a log afterwards

Comment: I have made sure of both Damien